# Choice and Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, biophysics, perception

Does the action of making a choice expend energy?

If any conscious choice is predetermined, it must always be taken towards a greater entropy state, which means it must somehow "know" ahead of time that the next state is of higher entropy. So, given two possible states with $E_1 > E_2$ to choose from, it could choose $E_2$ nevertheless (or could it?) And if it does, then does it take energy to choose one over the other?

And I am not talking about system choices that involve more energy being expanded; as a result, I am talking about the actual act of making a choice if such a thing exists.

Comment: Making a choice is a (not well-understood) process that most likely expends glucose within the brain.

Comment: "If any conscious choice is predetermined" (-> what do you mean?), "it must always be taken towards a greater entropy state" (-> the brain is not isolated, thermodynamic entropy must grow or stay constant in isolated systems). However, a functioning brain "burns calories". This stuff is complex, see e.g. Shroedinger's theory of negative entropy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_and_life

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because physics has no theory for brain function and thought.

Comment: If I choose between two actions by flipping a coin, am I making a choice ? Is the coin making a choice ? Or is this not really a choice at all ?